# PDF Open parameters on a mac via applescript

Tags: macos, pdf, applescript

How would you open a PDF with its "Open parameters" (i.e. page, highlight, nameddest, etc.) on a Mac using Applescript?

The "Open parameters" are described here:
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

In that document they state:

> In Mac OS, you can use the parameters when opening a PDF document with
>   an Apple event.

I've tried:

```
tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
    open file "[device:folder:file]" options "highlight = 10, 100, 10, 100"
end tell
```

...but this doesn't work. The file opens, but there is no highlight and console shows 'missing value'.

Comment: Does this help maybe?.... http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/17477

Comment: Or this? ... http://superuser.com/a/116237

Comment: At a guess, spaces should only appear _between_ options, so try `"highlight=10,100,10,100"`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't see how I'd specify the file name along with the URL params in either of those examples...

Comment: @foo I tried that, but same thing.  the file opens, without highlighting, and the console says 'missing value'

Comment: Acrobat's "AppleScript" support is notoriously awful so it's entirely possible it's just plain broken. I assume you've already googled the issue and not found anything helpful. You could try asking on the [applescript-users mailing list](https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/applescript-users); most pro scripters can be found there.

Comment: BTW, `missing value` is just an ordinary AppleScript value, similar to `None` in Python or `null` in JavaScript. It doesn't signify an error; it's just the default value used to indicate no other value was given.